# R paste after strsplit without duplicates

Tags: r, split, concatenation

I have a string in R

```
myname <- "Peter del Soreno Garfias"
```

I want to get rid of the second word and would like to have "Peter Soreno Garfias" in the end.

So I do a

```
strgSplitted <- unlist(strsplit(myname))
```

And put everything together

```
nameShort <- paste0(strgSplitted[[1]]," ",strgSplitted[1:length(strgSplitted)]
```

But what I get is

> "Peter Soreno, Peter Garfias"

How can I get

> "Peter Soreno Garfias"

?

Best

Comment: You can try `paste(strsplit(myname, " ")[[1]][-2], collapse = " ")`. Or for multiple elements `sapply(strsplit(myname, " "), function(x) paste(x[-2], collapse = " "))`.

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(myname))` is an incorrect R code. You should get an error in that line itself before moving ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use strsplit and remove the 2nd word

```
paste(unlist(strsplit(myname, " "))[-2], collapse = " ")
[1] "Peter Soreno Garfias"
```

If it is a specific word and not necessarily at the 2nd position, then you can replace that with blank:

```
sub("del", "", myname)
[1] "Peter  Soreno Garfias"
```

Or only keep words with Capital letters

```
library(stringr)
paste(str_extract_all(myname, "\\b[A-Z]\\w+")[[1]], collapse = " ")
[1] "Peter Soreno Garfias"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibly safer approach using `gsub`:

```
myname <- "Peter del Soreno Garfias"
output <- gsub("\\s+[a-z]+\\s+", " ", myname)
output

[1] "Peter Soreno Garfias"
```

The logic here is to remove any middle words which do not have any capital letters in them.

If you really just want to remove the second word from the name, we can also use `sub` for that:

```
sub("^(\\S+)\\s+\\S+(.*)", "\\1\\2", myname)
[1] "Peter Soreno Garfias"
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP wants to remove the middle words that do not have any capital letters in them?

Comment: @tmfmnk Because `del` is considered as a non critical part of the name, and therefore not part of the "real" name.  It's a possibly valid suggestion, except that sometimes these might actually be uppercase too (but not in the OP's example).